# How to exclusively style parent or child when hovering over either of them?

Tags: html, css, hover, parent-child, pointer-events

I have some very simple HTML that looks like

```
<div id="parent">
    <a href='#link' id="child">Child</a>
</div>
```

I want to style the parent when hovering over the parent and I want to style the child when hovering over the child. I never want both to be styled at the same time.

I tried various combinations of :hover and :not() selectors in SCSS. Googling didn't bring me far; most solutions I found just tell me how to style the parent when hovering over the child, which is the opposite of what I want.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646790/how-to-disable-parent-hover-when-hovering-over-child) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923922/hover-on-child-without-hover-effect-on-parent) workaround, both from 2013, but I was wondering whether there is a better, more modern way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only intend to support modern, evergreen browsers that support [`:has`](https://caniuse.com/css-has), then you can style `#parent` based on the following conditions:

- is hovered
- does not have a hovered child

That translates to a selector of such: `#parent:hover:not(:has(#child:hover))`.

In the example below, the `#parent` is red only when it is hovered and not its child:

```css
#parent:hover:not(:has(#child:hover)) {
  background: red;
}

#child:hover {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <a href='#link' id="child">Child</a>
</div>
```

Comment: The project I am working on is meant to be used exclusively by myself and my friends, I know the entire target demographic by name. Modern browser requirement is not an issue for my use case.
Works as intended, many thanks!

Comment: @SimonMaurer Do note that Firefox still requires a flag to be toggled for `:has` support, but otherwise all modern browsers based off Chromium or Webkit supports it already :)